# Dismissing a UIViewController from a UIActionSheet Class

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, uiviewcontroller, uiactionsheet

I created a `UIActionSheet` Class that will allow me to log out from anywhere within my app. the issue that I am having is once I hit logout button it should also dismiss the current `viewController` and go back to the login `viewController`. Below is a snippet of my code.

```
NSObject.h file 

@interface constants : NSObject<UIActionSheetDelegate>{

    UIActionSheet *msg;

}

-(void)presentMyActionSheet;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIView *viewForActionSheet;


NSObject.m file

-(void)presentMyActionSheet{

msg = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:nil delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" destructiveButtonTitle:@"Log Out" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];

[msg showInView:self.viewForActionSheet];

}
// actionsheet delegate protocol item
- (void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex: (NSInteger)buttonIndex{

    NSLog(@"button index = %ld", (long)buttonIndex);
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    if(buttonIndex == 0){
                [defaults setObject:nil forKey:@"acctInfo"];
                [defaults setBool:NO forKey:@"isLoggedOn"];

                NSLog(@"You logged out");
```

This is what I tried.

```
   viewController *controller = [[viewController alloc]init];
   [controller.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:NO];  
   [controller dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];
```

it does not work.

```
            }else{

                NSLog(@"You canceled logout");
            }

}

 viewController.h file

@interface viewController : UIViewController<UIActionSheetDelegate>

@property(nonatomic, retain)constants *obj;


viewController.m file

@synthesize obj;

{
    self.obj = [[constants alloc] init];
    self.obj.viewForActionSheet = self.view;
    [self.obj presentMyActionSheet];

    if([defaults boolForKey:@"isLoggedOn"]){

If I try it from here it crashes.
     //   [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:NO];
     //   [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];

    }
}
```

Any suggestions as to why it is not working?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried dismissing the action sheet first then popping the view controller?

Comment: @pnavk yes, when I try that the app crashes.

Answer (score 2):

You should use NSNotification o your own delegate in the object class.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
[self.viewForActionSheet.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

you could use the UIActionSheetDelegate Method `-(void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex`

For example:

```
 -(void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{

    if (buttonIndex == 1) {
        [self.navigationControllerler dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];}}
```